# MS ACCESS - How to calculate (Add/Subtract) weekdays

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to subtract a number of working days from a date using a variable in access.

This was working fine

```
JS = CstmDD - LdTm
```

But doesn't take into account the weekends,

```
JS = Weekday(CstmDD) - LdTm
```

Although the Customer due date (CstmDD) is 30/9/2022 and the lead time (LdTm) is 8 days the result (JS) is 28/12/1899 but it should be 27/09/2022

Any ideas why it's not working properly

Update..... More of the code below..

```
Dim LdTm As Long
    Dim CstmDD As Date
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strSQL2 As String
    Dim JS As Date

strSQL = "SELECT Sum(tblRouting.OpleadTm) AS SumOfOpleadTm, tblRouting.[Job Number] " & vbCrLf & _
        "FROM tblRouting " & vbCrLf & _
        "GROUP BY tblRouting.[Job Number] " & vbCrLf & _
        "HAVING (tblRouting.[Job Number])= " & EntJobNum
        
        LdTm = CurrentProject.Connection.Execute(strSQL).Fields("SumOfOpleadTm")
        
        strSQL2 = "SELECT tblManufactured.[Job Number], tblManufactured.[Customer Due Date] " & vbCrLf & _
        "FROM tblManufactured " & vbCrLf & _
        "WHERE (tblManufactured.[Job Number])=" & EntJobNum
        
        CstmDD = CurrentProject.Connection.Execute(strSQL2).Fields("Customer Due Date")
       
        JS = Weekday(CstmDD) - LdTm
        
        '  JS = CstmDD - LdTm
        MsgBox (LdTm) & vbNewLine & (CstmDD) & vbNewLine & (JS)
```

Comment: We need more than 1 line of context. Please post your FULL Access/JET Red SQL command or query.

Comment: [Weekday](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/weekday-function) is a function returning the number of the day in the week, (1 for Sunday, 2 for Monday, ...) so your subtracting the lead time from a value between 1 to 7.

Comment: @Dai: No, this is not because  the Access SQL engine is old. Plus, this is VBA, not SQL.

Comment: While Excel has a worksheet function (WorksheetFunction.Workday) to handle weekends, there is no equivalent in MsAccess, but you can find online some example on how to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: You can use `JS = DateAddWorkdays(LdTm, CstmDD)` (see link above) though that will return 2022-10-12, not 2022-09-27.